# How to unit test a Consumer<HeaderSpec>

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have the following definition in my code based on [Spring Integration enrichHeader with randomUUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33292265/spring-integration-enrichheader-with-randomuuid):

```
@Bean
public Consumer<HeaderEnricherSpec> uriHeaderEnricher() {
    return new Consumer<HeaderEnricherSpec>() {
        private final String TIMESTAMP = "Timestamp";
        private final String MESSAGE_ID = "MessageId";

    @Override
        public void accept(HeaderEnricherSpec t) {
            t.headerFunction(MarklogicMessageHandler.URI, 
                    m -> "/event/" +
                         format(m.getHeaders().get(TIMESTAMP)) + "/" +
                         m.getHeaders().get(MESSAGE_ID) +
                         ".xml");
        }

        private String format(Object object) {
            if (!(object instanceof String)) {
                return "";
            }
            String string = (String) object;
            return string.substring(0, 10).replaceAll("-", "/");
        }

    };
}
```

I'm a bit stymied, though on what a unit test for this code would look like. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So we want to isolate the class under test `Consumer<HeaderEnricherSpec>` and assert on any and all interactions that class has with other classes, in this case `HeaderEnricherSpec`. I'm not sure if you're using a mocking framework like Mockito or not, but I can give you an example in Mockito of how to test this well. The thing that is going to prove interesting is using an `ArgumentCaptor` to capture the lambda sent to `headerFunction` and then you can call that lambda in your test to ensure it is working as expected.

```
//This should invoke your bean method
@Autowired
private Consumer<HeaderEnricherSpec> consumer;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Function<WhateverTypeMIs, String>> lambdaCaptor; 

@Test
public void testAccept() {
    HeaderEnricherSpec spec = Mockito.mock(HeaderEnricherSpec.class);

    consumer.accept(spec);

    // Just showing you how to use the captor, don't forget to test URI
    verify(spec).headerFunction(any(), lambdaCaptor.capture());

    //This will be the lambda function you passed to `headerFunction`
    Function<WhateverTypeMIs, String> lambda = lambdaCaptor.getValue();

    //Now you need to call the lambda function just like you would if it were a separately testable function.
    String result = lambda.apply(m);
    //assertions on result string based on m input
}
```

Let me know if you need more help or guidance.

More info on ArgumentCaptor: [docs](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html), [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295891/how-to-use-argumentcaptor-for-stubbing)

[Using ArgumentCaptor as field](http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations)

Comment: Note: I did not compile this code so treat it as such.

Comment: The verify line is giving me an error. It doesn't like the any() (putting an empty string let the compiler past that) I then get the following error on headerfunction: `The method headerFunction(String, Function<Message<P>, Object>) in the type HeaderEnricherSpec is not applicable for the arguments (String, Function<Message<Object>, Object>)` (I also had to make some type changes in the definition of lambdaCaptor).

Comment: Hmmm, without trying to recreate your situation, my guess is that the compiler is unable to ensure the generic type of `Message` to be `P`. Maybe try making your captor loose and use `Object` instead of `P` for the generic type of `Message` and you may get passed this warning. This may put you in a position to have to cast back to `P` later, however.

Comment: I think it might be a Mockito bug--the P is a generic specification on the headerFunction definition

Comment: Yeah that does seem strange then. Did you try changing it to Object?

Comment: Changing what to object? If you mean the generic parameter on Message where I had control over it, yes, I did.

Comment: It turns out the issue was the compiler wasn't correctly notifying me that I was using the wrong `Function` class.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. That's always a frustrating problem. Glad you figured it out! Cheers.